# Change Checkout template based on products in cart

Tags: checkout, cart, template, onepage-checkout, products

This is a weird request from a client, the products can be purchased with or without logos adding on to them. However, when a product which requires a logo is added to the cart the checkout process needs to be slightly different as additional costs will be added afterwards.

I've tried setting a new session in order to store whether the cart has a product which requires a logo in it and using various if statements to overcome this request, example:

```
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php
                    $get_attributes = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
                    $attributes = $get_attributes['attributes_info'];
                    foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
                        if($attribute['value'] == 'Has Logo') {
                            $logo_cart = TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```

Using the $logo_cart variable I set it in the core/session, then use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLogoCart();
```

within if statements to change aspects of the checkout.

This is obviously not an ideal way of achieving this, especially since I am currently only setting the session once the customer hits the cart page so it's quite buggy if they're already on the checkout page.

Are there any suggestions on how I can achieve the above? I'm currently using the One Page Checkout module found here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/express-checkout-one-step-checkout.html

One method I've thought about is switching the entire template depending on what's in the cart, but I'm unsure which files I'd need to change within the module to achieve this.

EDIT:
Just to clarify, the entire process is to remain the same. I just need to remove a few options from the checkout, such as the shipping method, the review your order section, and display a new area, which are just template changes anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is will use observers and custom layout XML.
For that you will need to create your own extension. Inchoo has a nice [hello world article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/) that should get you started and you can read more about observers in this [Magento Board post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).

You will need to hook the `controller_action_layout_load_before` event. Add this to your `config.xml`.

```
<controller_action_layout_load_before>
    <observers>
        <[module]>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>[module]/observer</class>
            <method>addLayoutHandleObserver</method>
        </[module]>
    </observers>
</controller_action_layout_load_before>
```

Your `Observer` would use your code to check for the specific product and if present add a layout handle to the generate Layout XML. This will enable us to target it from a layout xml file.

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function addLayoutHandleObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        $logo_cart = false;
        foreach ($items as $_item) 
        {
            $get_attributes = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
            $attributes = $get_attributes['attributes_info'];
            foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
                if($attribute['value'] == 'Has Logo') {
                    $logo_cart = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
           if ($logo_cart) break;
        }

        if ($logo_cart)
        {
            $layout = $observer->getAction()->getLayout();
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('checkout_has_logo');
            $layout->generateXml();
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now we can add some custom layout updates from, for example, the `local.xml`.

```
<checkout_has_logo>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/onepage_logo.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_has_logo>
```

Comment: That is a brilliant answer. Will try implementing something based on your advice and let you know how I get on. +1 for the idea though!

Comment: Thanks, I've used it somewhat like this in https://github.com/magento-hackathon/layered-landing if you want to see it in action. Any questions be sure to ask!

Comment: @SanderMangel You can simply put break; after $logo_cart = true; in the loop. There is no reason of looping again if the required option is found.

Comment: @MagePsycho updated the answer :)

Comment: I've got it working so far that it uses the new observer class and $logo_cart is set to true, but it doesn't appear to add the new handle to load in a different template. I've added the checkout_has_logo reference to the local.xml file and created the file within the right location but still the old template is included. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind sorted that now! I changed the name "checkout.onepage" to "opcheckout.onepage" since I'm using the opcheckout extension. Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it to work

Comment: This is a great idea and a great piece of code. Give the man the bounty points already.

Comment: I just did, Marius, I assumed the bounty points were given when it was marked as the correct answer (This is the first time I've set a bounty), but apparently not!

Comment: Dear Sander,Can you please put your concept on my quesion http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39851/what-it-means-by-magento-cache-fast-backend-and-slow-backend