# what it means by Magento cache fast-backend and slow-backend?

Tags: configuration, cache, backend, local.xml

What it means by  cache

```
backend
slow_backend
slow_backend_store_data
auto_refresh_fast_cache
```

I have see this types of caches config in local.xml.additional  file.
I want to is know

**what is meant by this type of caches and**

**why this is used and which section is affected by it on Magento**

and
**I need details of explanation**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

maybe this helps:

> **The Two Level cache mechanisms**
>
> The « two level cache » system allows to get a fast cache backend and
>   a slow cache backend. The main problem here is that only file and
>   database structures allow the slow backend to be really efficient
>   because a “home made” structuring of these content can be done.
>
> With APC or Memcached, we can get a two way associative structure but
>   still very simple. Magento handles large data collections, with type,
>   category, groups, etc… A simple structure can’t really fulfill the
>   need of Magento’s cache. In order to be able to work properly, Magento
>   need a slow backend cache that could be structured properly and have
>   extended value/capabilities. In the fast_backend, we then only have a
>   key (element id) and the content of this key (the element that is
>   cached). It’s a bit like if you have a mailing system that store a
>   mail content with an ID and another DB that help structuring it with
>   folders and attributes. The “raw” data is stored in the fast_backend,
>   the intelligent mapping of these data is stored in the slow_backend.
>
> This way, Magento can selectively delete or update a key or a category
>   without having to flush all the cache every time an update is made.
>
> If you impose a “non configurable” slow cache backend to Magento, it
>   won’t be able to selectively clean the part of the cache that are
>   impacted by a manipulation, it then renders the whole caching
>   mechanism quite useless.

via https://www.nbs-system.co.uk/blog-2/magento-optimization-howto-en.html